# Elastic Search Phonetic Analysis plugin not working on Index

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-phonetic

I have successfully installed the Phonetic Analysis Plugin (version 2.2.0) - using the command "sudo bin/plugin install analysis-phonetic" - to my build of elastic search (version 2.3.4), after which I have restarted the elastic search service on the server. However, when I try to build the index I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\BadRequest400Exception' with message '{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"index_creation_exception","reason":"failed to create index"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Unknown TokenFilter type [phonetic] for [dbl_metaphone_filter]"},"status":400}'
```

It works perfectly fine on my local machine but not on my live server and I am out of ideas as to why it wouldn't be working. I would appreciate anything I could go back to my hosting company with for them to look into, as I imagine it might be a server configuration issue.

Here are the logs from the last few restarts:

```
[2016-08-02 11:14:19,167][INFO ][node                     ] [Sin-Eater] stopping ...
[2016-08-02 11:14:19,456][INFO ][node                     ] [Sin-Eater] stopped
[2016-08-02 11:14:19,456][INFO ][node                     ] [Sin-Eater] closing ...
[2016-08-02 11:14:19,491][INFO ][node                     ] [Sin-Eater] closed
[2016-08-02 11:14:38,137][WARN ][bootstrap                ] unable to load JNA native support library, native methods will be disabled.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/jna--1985354563/jna2578467607555190923.tmp: /tmp/jna--1985354563/jna2578467607555190923.tmp: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1968)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1893)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1854)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:795)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1062)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibraryFromClasspath(Native.java:761)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibrary(Native.java:736)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:131)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:195)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Natives.<clinit>(Natives.java:45)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.initializeNatives(Bootstrap.java:89)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:144)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:270)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:35)
[2016-08-02 11:14:38,142][WARN ][bootstrap                ] cannot check if running as root because JNA is not available
[2016-08-02 11:14:38,143][WARN ][bootstrap                ] cannot install syscall filters because JNA is not available
[2016-08-02 11:14:38,143][WARN ][bootstrap                ] cannot register console handler because JNA is not available
[2016-08-02 11:14:38,727][INFO ][node                     ] [Stonecutter] version[2.3.4], pid[3183], build[e455fd0/2016-06-30T11:24:31Z]
[2016-08-02 11:14:38,727][INFO ][node                     ] [Stonecutter] initializing ...
[2016-08-02 11:14:39,524][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Stonecutter] modules [lang-groovy, reindex, lang-expression], plugins [], sites []
[2016-08-02 11:14:39,600][INFO ][env                      ] [Stonecutter] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (/dev/xvda1)]], net usable_space [384.6gb], net total_space [438gb], spins? [no], types [ext3]
[2016-08-02 11:14:39,600][INFO ][env                      ] [Stonecutter] heap size [990.7mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2016-08-02 11:14:39,600][WARN ][env                      ] [Stonecutter] max file descriptors [65535] for elasticsearch process likely too low, consider increasing to at least [65536]
[2016-08-02 11:14:42,034][INFO ][node                     ] [Stonecutter] initialized
[2016-08-02 11:14:42,034][INFO ][node                     ] [Stonecutter] starting ...
[2016-08-02 11:14:42,253][INFO ][transport                ] [Stonecutter] publish_address {localhost/127.0.0.1:9300}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9300}
[2016-08-02 11:14:42,260][INFO ][discovery                ] [Stonecutter] elasticsearch/ujWKZjVITlqGrx2HUtiWAA
[2016-08-02 11:14:45,316][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Stonecutter] new_master {Stonecutter}{ujWKZjVITlqGrx2HUtiWAA}{127.0.0.1}{localhost/127.0.0.1:9300}, reason: zen-disco-join(elected_as_master, [0] joins received)
[2016-08-02 11:14:45,330][INFO ][http                     ] [Stonecutter] publish_address {localhost/127.0.0.1:9200}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9200}
[2016-08-02 11:14:45,331][INFO ][node                     ] [Stonecutter] started
[2016-08-02 11:14:46,088][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Stonecutter] recovered [9] indices into cluster_state
[2016-08-02 11:14:50,481][INFO ][cluster.routing.allocation] [Stonecutter] Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [GREEN] (reason: [shards started [[candidates][0]] ...]).
[2016-08-02 11:48:54,442][INFO ][node                     ] [Stonecutter] stopping ...
[2016-08-02 11:48:54,515][INFO ][node                     ] [Stonecutter] stopped
[2016-08-02 11:48:54,515][INFO ][node                     ] [Stonecutter] closing ...
[2016-08-02 11:48:54,521][INFO ][node                     ] [Stonecutter] closed
[2016-08-02 11:48:59,195][WARN ][bootstrap                ] unable to load JNA native support library, native methods will be disabled.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/jna--1985354563/jna8964183078405864074.tmp: /tmp/jna--1985354563/jna8964183078405864074.tmp: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1968)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1893)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1854)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:795)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1062)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibraryFromClasspath(Native.java:761)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibrary(Native.java:736)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:131)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:195)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Natives.<clinit>(Natives.java:45)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.initializeNatives(Bootstrap.java:89)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:144)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:270)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:35)
[2016-08-02 11:48:59,206][WARN ][bootstrap                ] cannot check if running as root because JNA is not available
[2016-08-02 11:48:59,206][WARN ][bootstrap                ] cannot install syscall filters because JNA is not available
[2016-08-02 11:48:59,207][WARN ][bootstrap                ] cannot register console handler because JNA is not available
[2016-08-02 11:48:59,447][INFO ][node                     ] [Star-Lord] version[2.3.4], pid[8651], build[e455fd0/2016-06-30T11:24:31Z]
[2016-08-02 11:48:59,447][INFO ][node                     ] [Star-Lord] initializing ...
[2016-08-02 11:48:59,942][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Star-Lord] modules [lang-groovy, reindex, lang-expression], plugins [], sites []
[2016-08-02 11:48:59,964][INFO ][env                      ] [Star-Lord] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (/dev/xvda1)]], net usable_space [384.6gb], net total_space [438gb], spins? [no], types [ext3]
[2016-08-02 11:48:59,964][INFO ][env                      ] [Star-Lord] heap size [990.7mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2016-08-02 11:48:59,964][WARN ][env                      ] [Star-Lord] max file descriptors [65535] for elasticsearch process likely too low, consider increasing to at least [65536]
[2016-08-02 11:49:01,706][INFO ][node                     ] [Star-Lord] initialized
[2016-08-02 11:49:01,706][INFO ][node                     ] [Star-Lord] starting ...
[2016-08-02 11:49:01,792][INFO ][transport                ] [Star-Lord] publish_address {localhost/127.0.0.1:9300}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9300}
[2016-08-02 11:49:01,796][INFO ][discovery                ] [Star-Lord] elasticsearch/eF2MMcsqRy2qiE9BdUPZqA
[2016-08-02 11:49:04,844][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Star-Lord] new_master {Star-Lord}{eF2MMcsqRy2qiE9BdUPZqA}{127.0.0.1}{localhost/127.0.0.1:9300}, reason: zen-disco-join(elected_as_master, [0] joins received)
[2016-08-02 11:49:04,861][INFO ][http                     ] [Star-Lord] publish_address {localhost/127.0.0.1:9200}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9200}
[2016-08-02 11:49:04,862][INFO ][node                     ] [Star-Lord] started
[2016-08-02 11:49:05,533][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Star-Lord] recovered [9] indices into cluster_state
[2016-08-02 11:49:07,552][INFO ][cluster.routing.allocation] [Star-Lord] Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [GREEN] (reason: [shards started [[candidates][0]] ...]).
[2016-08-02 11:50:10,518][INFO ][node                     ] [Star-Lord] stopping ...
[2016-08-02 11:50:10,603][INFO ][node                     ] [Star-Lord] stopped
[2016-08-02 11:50:10,603][INFO ][node                     ] [Star-Lord] closing ...
[2016-08-02 11:50:10,613][INFO ][node                     ] [Star-Lord] closed
[2016-08-02 11:50:34,639][WARN ][bootstrap                ] unable to load JNA native support library, native methods will be disabled.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/jna--1985354563/jna3428601699133674228.tmp: /tmp/jna--1985354563/jna3428601699133674228.tmp: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1968)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1893)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1854)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:795)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1062)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibraryFromClasspath(Native.java:761)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibrary(Native.java:736)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:131)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:195)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Natives.<clinit>(Natives.java:45)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.initializeNatives(Bootstrap.java:89)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:144)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:270)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:35)
[2016-08-02 11:50:34,642][WARN ][bootstrap                ] cannot check if running as root because JNA is not available
[2016-08-02 11:50:34,642][WARN ][bootstrap                ] cannot install syscall filters because JNA is not available
[2016-08-02 11:50:34,642][WARN ][bootstrap                ] cannot register console handler because JNA is not available
[2016-08-02 11:50:34,876][INFO ][node                     ] [Ororo Munroe] version[2.3.4], pid[8998], build[e455fd0/2016-06-30T11:24:31Z]
[2016-08-02 11:50:34,876][INFO ][node                     ] [Ororo Munroe] initializing ...
[2016-08-02 11:50:35,391][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Ororo Munroe] modules [lang-groovy, reindex, lang-expression], plugins [], sites []
[2016-08-02 11:50:35,414][INFO ][env                      ] [Ororo Munroe] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (/dev/xvda1)]], net usable_space [384.6gb], net total_space [438gb], spins? [no], types [ext3]
[2016-08-02 11:50:35,414][INFO ][env                      ] [Ororo Munroe] heap size [990.7mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2016-08-02 11:50:35,414][WARN ][env                      ] [Ororo Munroe] max file descriptors [65535] for elasticsearch process likely too low, consider increasing to at least [65536]
[2016-08-02 11:50:37,129][INFO ][node                     ] [Ororo Munroe] initialized
[2016-08-02 11:50:37,129][INFO ][node                     ] [Ororo Munroe] starting ...
[2016-08-02 11:50:37,230][INFO ][transport                ] [Ororo Munroe] publish_address {localhost/127.0.0.1:9300}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9300}
[2016-08-02 11:50:37,234][INFO ][discovery                ] [Ororo Munroe] elasticsearch/Xe2g_nTrSa6jFecX6Nm-jQ
[2016-08-02 11:50:40,281][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Ororo Munroe] new_master {Ororo Munroe}{Xe2g_nTrSa6jFecX6Nm-jQ}{127.0.0.1}{localhost/127.0.0.1:9300}, reason: zen-disco-join(elected_as_master, [0] joins received)
[2016-08-02 11:50:40,301][INFO ][http                     ] [Ororo Munroe] publish_address {localhost/127.0.0.1:9200}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9200}
[2016-08-02 11:50:40,301][INFO ][node                     ] [Ororo Munroe] started
[2016-08-02 11:50:40,957][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Ororo Munroe] recovered [9] indices into cluster_state
[2016-08-02 11:50:42,871][INFO ][cluster.routing.allocation] [Ororo Munroe] Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [GREEN] (reason: [shards started [[candidates][0], [candidates][0]] ...]).
[2016-08-02 11:56:42,400][INFO ][node                     ] [Ororo Munroe] stopping ...
[2016-08-02 11:56:42,489][INFO ][node                     ] [Ororo Munroe] stopped
[2016-08-02 11:56:42,490][INFO ][node                     ] [Ororo Munroe] closing ...
[2016-08-02 11:56:42,499][INFO ][node                     ] [Ororo Munroe] closed
[2016-08-02 11:56:44,037][WARN ][bootstrap                ] unable to load JNA native support library, native methods will be disabled.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/jna--1985354563/jna2770571767363893923.tmp: /tmp/jna--1985354563/jna2770571767363893923.tmp: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1968)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1893)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1854)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:795)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1062)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibraryFromClasspath(Native.java:761)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibrary(Native.java:736)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:131)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:195)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Natives.<clinit>(Natives.java:45)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.initializeNatives(Bootstrap.java:89)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:144)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:270)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:35)
[2016-08-02 11:56:44,039][WARN ][bootstrap                ] cannot check if running as root because JNA is not available
[2016-08-02 11:56:44,039][WARN ][bootstrap                ] cannot install syscall filters because JNA is not available
[2016-08-02 11:56:44,039][WARN ][bootstrap                ] cannot register console handler because JNA is not available
[2016-08-02 11:56:44,273][INFO ][node                     ] [Phantom Rider] version[2.3.4], pid[10105], build[e455fd0/2016-06-30T11:24:31Z]
[2016-08-02 11:56:44,273][INFO ][node                     ] [Phantom Rider] initializing ...
[2016-08-02 11:56:44,775][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Phantom Rider] modules [lang-groovy, reindex, lang-expression], plugins [], sites []
[2016-08-02 11:56:44,797][INFO ][env                      ] [Phantom Rider] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (/dev/xvda1)]], net usable_space [384.6gb], net total_space [438gb], spins? [no], types [ext3]
[2016-08-02 11:56:44,797][INFO ][env                      ] [Phantom Rider] heap size [990.7mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2016-08-02 11:56:44,797][WARN ][env                      ] [Phantom Rider] max file descriptors [65535] for elasticsearch process likely too low, consider increasing to at least [65536]
[2016-08-02 11:56:46,555][INFO ][node                     ] [Phantom Rider] initialized
[2016-08-02 11:56:46,555][INFO ][node                     ] [Phantom Rider] starting ...
[2016-08-02 11:56:46,640][INFO ][transport                ] [Phantom Rider] publish_address {localhost/127.0.0.1:9300}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9300}
[2016-08-02 11:56:46,645][INFO ][discovery                ] [Phantom Rider] elasticsearch/2_woHzoWR2K42nI-wEI4rQ
[2016-08-02 11:56:49,703][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Phantom Rider] new_master {Phantom Rider}{2_woHzoWR2K42nI-wEI4rQ}{127.0.0.1}{localhost/127.0.0.1:9300}, reason: zen-disco-join(elected_as_master, [0] joins received)
[2016-08-02 11:56:49,721][INFO ][http                     ] [Phantom Rider] publish_address {localhost/127.0.0.1:9200}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9200}
[2016-08-02 11:56:49,721][INFO ][node                     ] [Phantom Rider] started
[2016-08-02 11:56:50,342][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Phantom Rider] recovered [9] indices into cluster_state
[2016-08-02 11:56:52,574][INFO ][cluster.routing.allocation] [Phantom Rider] Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [GREEN] (reason: [shards started [[candidates][0]] ...]).
[2016-08-02 17:12:28,899][INFO ][node                     ] [Phantom Rider] stopping ...
[2016-08-02 17:12:28,978][INFO ][node                     ] [Phantom Rider] stopped
[2016-08-02 17:12:28,979][INFO ][node                     ] [Phantom Rider] closing ...
[2016-08-02 17:12:28,988][INFO ][node                     ] [Phantom Rider] closed
[2016-08-02 17:12:41,464][WARN ][bootstrap                ] unable to load JNA native support library, native methods will be disabled.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/jna--1985354563/jna8820167229095667602.tmp: /tmp/jna--1985354563/jna8820167229095667602.tmp: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1968)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1893)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1854)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:795)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1062)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibraryFromClasspath(Native.java:761)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibrary(Native.java:736)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:131)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:195)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Natives.<clinit>(Natives.java:45)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.initializeNatives(Bootstrap.java:89)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:144)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:270)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:35)
[2016-08-02 17:12:41,466][WARN ][bootstrap                ] cannot check if running as root because JNA is not available
[2016-08-02 17:12:41,466][WARN ][bootstrap                ] cannot install syscall filters because JNA is not available
[2016-08-02 17:12:41,467][WARN ][bootstrap                ] cannot register console handler because JNA is not available
[2016-08-02 17:12:41,700][INFO ][node                     ] [Abdul Alhazred] version[2.3.4], pid[24366], build[e455fd0/2016-06-30T11:24:31Z]
[2016-08-02 17:12:41,700][INFO ][node                     ] [Abdul Alhazred] initializing ...
[2016-08-02 17:12:42,195][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Abdul Alhazred] modules [lang-groovy, reindex, lang-expression], plugins [], sites []
[2016-08-02 17:12:42,217][INFO ][env                      ] [Abdul Alhazred] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (/dev/xvda1)]], net usable_space [384.6gb], net total_space [438gb], spins? [no], types [ext3]
[2016-08-02 17:12:42,217][INFO ][env                      ] [Abdul Alhazred] heap size [990.7mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2016-08-02 17:12:42,217][WARN ][env                      ] [Abdul Alhazred] max file descriptors [65535] for elasticsearch process likely too low, consider increasing to at least [65536]
[2016-08-02 17:12:43,922][INFO ][node                     ] [Abdul Alhazred] initialized
[2016-08-02 17:12:43,922][INFO ][node                     ] [Abdul Alhazred] starting ...
[2016-08-02 17:12:44,024][INFO ][transport                ] [Abdul Alhazred] publish_address {localhost/127.0.0.1:9300}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9300}
[2016-08-02 17:12:44,028][INFO ][discovery                ] [Abdul Alhazred] elasticsearch/1GE8MlQpRziXqFfMPaiLBA
[2016-08-02 17:12:47,082][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Abdul Alhazred] new_master {Abdul Alhazred}{1GE8MlQpRziXqFfMPaiLBA}{127.0.0.1}{localhost/127.0.0.1:9300}, reason: zen-disco-join(elected_as_master, [0] joins received)
[2016-08-02 17:12:47,097][INFO ][http                     ] [Abdul Alhazred] publish_address {localhost/127.0.0.1:9200}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9200}
[2016-08-02 17:12:47,097][INFO ][node                     ] [Abdul Alhazred] started
[2016-08-02 17:12:47,728][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Abdul Alhazred] recovered [9] indices into cluster_state
[2016-08-02 17:12:49,652][INFO ][cluster.routing.allocation] [Abdul Alhazred] Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [GREEN] (reason: [shards started [[candidates][0]] ...]).
```

ps -edf | grep elastic Output:

```
jtcpanel 10753 10693  0 05:26 pts/0    00:00:00 grep elastic
494      24366     1  0 Aug02 ?        00:15:43 /usr/bin/java -Xms256m -Xmx1g -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch -cp /usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/elasticsearch-2.3.4.jar:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/* org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch start -p /var/run/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.pid -d -Des.default.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch -Des.default.path.logs=/var/log/elasticsearch -Des.default.path.data=/var/lib/elasticsearch -Des.default.path.conf=/etc/elasticsearch
```

Comment: Can you show the logs of your ES server when you started it?

Comment: @Val, apologies for the delay it's been a mission getting them out of my hosting company (I do not have sudo access). I have added the logs as requested.

Comment: Have you changed the `tmpdir` path in sysconfig? Can you provide the output you get from `ps -edf | grep elastic`?

Comment: @Val, we haven't changed the tmpdir as far as I know. I have added the output from 'ps -edf | grep elastic'.